# MCCordovaPLugin - Package R does not exist

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, cordova, push-notification, ionic

I'm traying integrate Marketing Cloud Push Notifications using MCCordovaPlugin with Ionic 3, in iOS works fine, but when I compile for Android, console sends Error:

> Package R does not exist

Cordova version: 7.1.0
Ionic CLI version: 3.19.0

The app is a clean installation and only implements MCCordovaPlugin.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you have gotten anywhere with this yet, but 
Gradle build tool is required as a dependency for developing Cordova on Android platform. Do you have this tool installed?

https://gradle.org/install/#manually

Comment: Yes I have Gradle installed

Gradle 4.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-12-06 09:05:06 UTC
Revision:     cf7821a6f79f8e2a598df21780e3ff7ce8db2b82

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_144 (Oracle Corporation 25.144-b01)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.2 x86_64

Comment: Also, make sure you don't skip the part about adding your path to environment variables. export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-4.4.1/bin

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix is to go to the file and add it manually or create a bash script to automate it if you use build server.

Just type following:

`import {your.app.packagename}.R;`